# check if all table rows are equal

Tags: sql, sql-server

There are two tables with identical structure.
Let's assume the number of rows in both is equal.
how would you check if all rows are equal? Is there any faster way than comparing every column value of a given row with the same id in both tables?

Comment: By equal you mean that every value in each row is the same?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM table1
EXCEPT
SELECT * FROM table2
```

If anything is returned then they are not equal.

Comment: As Eric correctly points out, this doesn't work if table1 is a subset of table2

Comment: And doesn't work in case of doubled rows (e.g. two rows with same values).

Answer (score 8):

Abe's answer is correct, but only if they have the same number of rows. (I misread the question when I wrote my original response "condemning" his answer.) If table1 may be a subset of (a larger) table2 or vice versa, I would try:

```
if 
(
not exists ( select * from table1
             except
             select * from table2
           )
and
not exists ( select * from table2
             except
             select * from table1
           )
)
```

This gives true if they are the same, and false if they are different.

Comment: The logic is right, but I had problem with this query because of first select, it was not compiling. Changes first "Select" with "IF" to set a variable and it worked perfectly. THanks